# Testing the Difference between Two Time Series ~ Similar to paired t-test

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, t-test, inference, p-value

I hope everyone is doing well.  I have two time series data sets (Time Series 1) and (Time Series 2). These two series are produced monthly (from 1-2020 to 12-2020) 12 data points. Thus, I took the difference (diff = Time Series 1 - Time Series 2) at each month. I would like to test whether the mean of this difference (diff data set) equals zero - a test that is similar to paired t-test.  What is a valid statistical test in this case? I didn't think paired t-test is valid here because it is a time series.  I include the plots to illustrate the data set.

Other posts suggested fitting ARIMA model.  I don't think it's valid because I only got 12 data points.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try testing for stationarity of the difference time series.  If that is the case, then proceed to fit a model to the difference, e.g. AR(p), and examine the test results for the constant term accordingly.  In other words, if you can establish that the difference is a well behaved mean-zero stochastic process, then you would have want you want.

Although in this case, with such a small sample size, such analysis has little statistical power.  I would recommend a resampling based approach for this situation.